# ADO.NET Entity Framework, Northwind, and Employee.Orders > 0

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

So I'm trying to work on a sample app. Trying to dig into ADO.NET Entity Framework. I get an employee back using a method with LINQ like this:

```
    public IList<Employee> FindByLastName(string lastName)
    {
        IList<Employee> emps;
        var e = from emp in _ctx.Employees where emp.LastName == lastName select emp;
            emps = e.ToList<Employee>();
        return emps;
    }
```

Then in one of my Unit Tests I have **emps[0].Orders.Count > 0** and this comes back false.
So my Orders property is not loading. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
Any thoughts on how you incorporate this into this Load()/Include stuff into a repository pattern?

Do I have to do something lame like

```
public IList<Employee> GetEmployeeById(int id, bool includeOrders)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think theres a generic best way to do this, rather than saying include orders, I'd perhaps return lazy lists, lists that- when first used, will call the Load method under the covers first.

Comment: Ok... I saw someone talking about lazy lists over on a blog post. I guess I'll have to inherit from Employee to replace the plain list with a lazy one.

Comment: You'll probably need to have an Employee class that isn't associated with the Employee class defined by entity framework, and then map them in your repository. You'll also need to worry about making changes to the List of models, and how those changes are persisted back to the repo..

Comment: I've been down the same road with the EF, in my case I decided to postpone trying to build a repository pattern on top of it, but my reasons also included issues with validation and work units.

Comment: I think this reinforces my decision to use NHibernate on everything else except this one Northwind sample for work. Maybe Microsoft can do better by version 2 (or 3).

Comment: Perhaps, you can do the lazy loading an pushing back to entity framework if dont rely on the entity generation (or map to clean domain models), nhibernate doesn't magically solve the lazy loading problem, you'll either get an n+1 problem, or need to specifically inform nhibernate that..*cont*

Comment: .. you want to prefetch the child collection, which brings it back on par with Include.

Comment: need to play around more with my sample. Then I'll post a follow up with what direction I went in. Thanks meandmycode for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method, and you may be better writing the query less linq like:

```
public IList<Employee> FindByLastName(string lastName)    
{
    return _ctx.Employees
        .Include("Orders")
        .Where(emp => emp.LastName == lastName)
        .ToList();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of using an Include statement to load your Orders.

```
public IList<Employee> FindByLastName(string lastName)
{
    IList<Employee> emps;
    var e = from emp in _ctx.Employees.Include("Orders") where emp.LastName == lastName select emp;
        emps = e.ToList<Employee>();
    return emps;
}
```

This will result in a more complex join at the SQL side, but it does have the benefit of a single trip to the database and a smaller scope of records than the Load() example would return.  I'd try them both and see what works best for you.